# How do I make angular-ui bootstrap accordion group work in html5mode

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angularjs-routing

If I enable html5mode to true in my config module, the "hyperlink" that opens the accordion-group reroutes the url back to the base url.  Not only does the accordion group not open, but you are rerouted.  I had the accordion-group working fine when html5mode was not enabled.

Is there a simple fix for this, or am I going to have to go deep into the angularjs-ui source?  Or am I just out of luck with html5mode?
My accordion code is pretty simple:

```
<accordion close-others='true'>
<accordion-group ng-repeat='trip in retrieved.iss' heading='ISS:  {{trip.date}}'>
    <p class='deleteItem' ng-click='deleteItem(trip.uniqueCount)'>X</p>
    <p><span class='btn-group ' data-toggle='buttons-checkbox'>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary small-btn' ng-model='individualRadioModel' btn-radio="'Mine'">Mine</button>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary small-btn' ng-model='individualRadioModel' btn-radio="'All'">All</button>
        </span></p>
    <p ng-repeat='student in trip.studentList | matchStudents:individualRadioModel'>{{student}}</p>
</accordion-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use not use an older version of Angularjs.  The problem was with 1.0.4.  Moving to 1.0.6 or beyond, and the problem disappears.

Don't be an old fogey like me. Update your libraries, kids.